# How to make lazy loading of Vuex modules correctly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuex

I try to register them this way. 
When calling `store.state['CHAT_BASE'].someData` throws an error trying to get a value of undefined. 
With static imports, everything works.

**vuex file**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import createLogger from 'vuex/dist/logger';

Vue.use(Vuex);

const enableLogger = false, /* You can do this: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' */
    store = new Vuex.Store({
        strict: false,
        plugins: enableLogger ? [createLogger()] : [],
        modules: {
            COMMON: () => import('./modules/common'),

            /* Operators cabinet. */
            RMS_REQUESTS: () => import('./modules/rms/operators_cabinet/requests'),

            /* Request tree. */
            RMS_PROCESS_DATA: () => import('./modules/rms/request_tree/process_data'),
            RMS_FIELDS: () => import('./modules/rms/request_tree/fields'),
            RMS_STATUSES: () => import('./modules/rms/request_tree/statuses'),

            /* Chat. */
            CHAT_COMMON: () => import('./modules/chat/common'),
            CHAT_BASE: () => import('./modules/chat/base'),
            CHAT_MESSAGE: () => import('./modules/chat/message'),
            CHAT_SETTING: () => import('./modules/chat/setting'),
            CHAT_HISTORY: () => import('./modules/chat/history')
        }
    });

export default store;
```

And I tried like this

```
import('./modules/chat/base.js')
      .then(module=> {
           store.registerModule('CHAT_BASE', module.default);
      });
```

But in this case, the module loads even when it is not needed. On the page where the Vue-component is not loading.

How to make lazy loading in one file?

Comment: There is no *documention on VueX* site that tells it's possible. Vue components could be asyncrounously loaded but I don't think VueX modules could be without wraping the code or using a library like `vuex-async-module`